# Only 1 row in recordset but all rows in table get updated

Tags: vb6, ado, firebird

The query retrieves a single record as is confirmed by the recordcount but every single row in the table gets updated

I am using vb6 and ms ado 2.8

The Firebird version is 2.5.4.26856 (x64).

Firebird ODBC driver 2.0.3.154

The computer is windows 7 home edition 64 bit

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim cs As String
Dim dbPath As String

dbPath = "c:\Parkes\Parkes.fdb"
cs = "DRIVER={Firebird/Interbase(r) Driver}; DBNAME=localhost:" & dbPath & "; UID=SYSDBA; PWD=masterkey;"
cn.ConnectionString = cs
cn.Open

Dim sQuery As String

sQuery = "select memo from clients where clientID = 10021 "
rs.Open sQuery, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If rs.BOF <> True Or rs.EOF <> True Then
'putting msgbox rs.recordcount here confirms only 1 record in recordset
    rs.Movefirst
    rs.Fields("memo") = "blah"
    rs.Update

End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

If I alter the query slightly by also selecting a second column, the client surname then only rows with the same value in the surname column as that of of the row where the clientid is 10021 get edited.

```
sQuery = "select memo, surname from clients where clientID = 10021 "
```

I cannot understand how more than one row should be edited when the recordset contains only a single row

EDIT: Having read around the web a bit this is my understanding of what is happening. 
It seems that the update method identifies which records to update based on the selected columns in the recordset.
So if you select fields a,b,c,d and are updating field a, it will only update records in the database whose values for a,b,c,d match those in the recordset.
The best way to ensure that you only update a single record is to include the primary key in the selected fields.
So if I had written my query as in the line below, only a single record would have been updated because the clientID column contains unique values.

```
sQuery = "select memo, clientID from clients where clientID = 10021 "
```

It makes sense thinking about it but the way I wrote the query originally seems to work fine, in my experience, with other databases or am I wrong?

Comment: I would guess this should be considered a bug in the driver; your expectation that it should only update the selected record is right (as far as I know, I don't regularly use ADO or ODBC). The workaround to include the primary key is a good workaround, alternatively you could include the pseudocolumn `RDB$DB_KEY` which identifies the record as well.

Comment: @mark Rotteveel, after reading your comment, I tried the same code using ADO and an Access database. Only one record was updated, supporting your suggestion that this is a bug in the firebird odbc driver. I am glad if this is the case because otherwise I have been doing things wrong for a long time! Thank you!

Comment: You might want to create a bug report on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/ODBC

Comment: @mark Rotteveel, yes,  I have done that :-) http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

Comment: I assume you mean: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/ODBC-186

Comment: Yes and It has been replied to already. It is not a bug but is the expected behaviour. Knowing that, it's not a big problem to plan queries taking it into account.

Comment: Ah, You had already responded on the bug tracker comments section but that wasn't visible to me when I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code everything was fine and only update one row. I only want to suggest you a simple way to check whether record exist or not. that could be like this:

```
if rs.rows.count > 0 then
   ' no need to move recordset to first by default its on the first row
end if
```